# Cordova 3.4 webview inability to expand with content automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I thought this problem might have been asked before but i could not find a good keyword to search.

My problem is webview's height does not "grow" with the content inside.

The scenario is as below:

I have 1 div with 5 buttons with 200px height each, so it takes 1000px total.

if the screen is only of 900px height, there will be scroll bar and this is what i want.

Each button will toggle content to append itself.

If one content takes 200px, total height with one expanded content will be 1200px.

The problem is the screen will still act like 1000px and user cannot scroll to the very bottom.

Users have to scroll to the very top for a handful of time, and it will become normal.

One workaround for this issue is to set the height of div once again after extra content is shown like $(div).height($(div).height());

i wonder is there any proper solution for this issue?

Comment: So are we supposed to implement this ourselves or are you going to supply 'working' code?

Comment: Hi Adar, my project team is implementing this. Are you suggesting this is a worklight issue? I regard the code i supplied as temporary fix and am seeking some proper and tidier solution.  Thanks

Comment: I absolutely do not suggest that. I am asking you to provide a project that can be debugged.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your comment. I will try to see if i can provide sample project. Have you encountered this kind of issue before?

Comment: Nope, I did not. And it also does not sound to me like something that should be done for you. Sounds normal.

Comment: i understand this may not be handled automatically. this question is sort of finding a tidier way / code to deal with this issue.

Comment: Did my answer worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have in the html or body tag, or in a main container div a fixed height with overflow:hidden